# "cordova plugin add" giving Not Found: 404 errors

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I am trying to add the media-capture plugin via

`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-media-capture`

as per the instructions here: http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/capture/

but I am getting the following error:

```
npm http GET http://registry.cordova.io/cordova-plugin-media-capture
npm http 404 http://registry.cordova.io/cordova-plugin-media-capture
Error: 404 Not Found: cordova-plugin-media-capture
```

**EDIT**

I have now updated npm and cordova and I am now getting:

```
TypeError: Request path contains unescaped characters
```

Comment: update npm? `sudo npm install npm -g`

Comment: same result, good idea though.

Comment: I'm getting this too, for any plugin I attempt to add :-(

Answer (score 0):

You can add it directly from github reference:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media-capture
```

Comment: Mmmm. The plot thickens. This command gives: 
`Fetching plugin "https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media-capture" via git
 clone
Installing "cordova-plugin-media-capture" for android
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-file" via plugin registry
npm http GET http://registry.cordova.io/cordova-plugin-file
npm http 404 http://registry.cordova.io/cordova-plugin-file
Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-media-capture':Error: 404 Not Found: cordova-p
lugin-file`

Comment: seems that there is the cordova-plugin-file as a dependency. It it first : cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file then add your plugin.

Comment: I already have that plugin in the project. I've been using the file plugin for a couple of months

Comment: hey you find any solution i also facing same problem which you get in past.

Answer (score 0):

The plugins have moved from `cordova.io` to `npmjs.org`.

Try using this:

```
http://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-plugin-media-capture
```

If this doesn't work for you, then you need to update your `cordova` binaries.

```
npm rm cordova
npm install -g cordova // get a new shiny one!
```